# github issues api and jq filter and grep

Tags: linux, date, time, github-api, jq

I'm using GitHub enterprise API to get the list of issues in one of my repo. 
But, I need to filter the output, so that I can get the list of issues which was created since last one week.

Below is where I've reached so far & it is working fine. I need help in filtering the issues created only since last week.

```
#!/bin/sh
tot_page=`curl -k -I https://<my_pat>:x-oauth-basic@github.developer.blah.com/api/v3/repos/droppin/remotedev/issues?state=all\&per_page=10 2>/dev/null |  awk -F'[&=<>]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^page$/) {kk=$(i+1)}} END{print kk}'`;
echo "$tot_page"
for ((i=1;i<=tot_page;i++))
do
        curl -k https://<my_pat>:x-oauth-basic@github.developer.blah.com/api/v3/repos/droppin/remotedev/issues?state=all\&per_page=2\&page=$i 2>/dev/null | 
        jq -r '.[] | 
          "\(.number)" + "\t\t" + "\(.assignee.login)" 
           + "\t\t\t" +  "\(.state)" + "\t\t" 
           + "\(.created_at) | date("'
done
```

Appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Sample JSON output as requested.

```
[
      {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1558",
    "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1558/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1558/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1558/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1558",
    "id": 282346710,
    "number": 1558,
    "title": "Fix a try-catch example",
    "user": {
      "login": "zogwarg",
      "id": 6682272,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/6682272?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/zogwarg",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zogwarg/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "labels": [

    ],
    "state": "open",
    "locked": false,
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [

    ],
    "milestone": null,
    "comments": 0,
    "created_at": "2017-12-15T07:56:31Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-12-15T07:56:31Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "author_association": "NONE",
    "pull_request": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/pulls/1558",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1558",
      "diff_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1558.diff",
      "patch_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1558.patch"
    },
    "body": "Fixing a bad syntax in a try-catch example\r\n\r\nIt was probably based on the inputs builtin definition,\r\nThe if statement was messed up and the semi-colon actually belongs to the function definition."
  },
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1557",
    "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1557/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1557/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/issues/1557/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1557",
    "id": 282289185,
    "number": 1557,
    "title": "Compiling for tvOS",
    "user": {
      "login": "larryaasen",
      "id": 325973,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/325973?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/larryaasen",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/larryaasen/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "labels": [

    ],
    "state": "open",
    "locked": false,
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [

    ],
    "milestone": null,
    "comments": 0,
    "created_at": "2017-12-15T01:05:47Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-12-15T01:05:47Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "author_association": "CONTRIBUTOR",
    "body": "I attempted to update the compile-ios.sh file for tvOS to build the library for use in an Apple TV app. I am not able to get it to link. Has anyone been able to compile the library for tvOS?\r\n\r\nHere is the error message:\r\n/opt/local/bin/ranlib: object: .libs/libonig.a(regerror.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)\r\n\r\nAttached the script file:\r\n[compile-tvos.sh.zip](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/files/1561265/compile-tvos.sh.zip)\r\n"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample JSON.

Comment: Hi @peak, shared the sample JSON with couple of entities..

Comment: @pprmdas, ok, post the expected result

Comment: Expected output should be the list of github issues along with the `assignees`  that was created last week.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self-advertising. You can do this neatly with jf

```
pip install jf
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/alhoo/jf/issues" | jf 'filter(age(x.created_at) < age("1 week"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jq:

```
# Input should be a date of the form: 2017-12-15T01:05:47
def older(days):
  (now - (strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%T") | mktime)) #  seconds 
  >  (days*24*3600);

.[]
| (.created_at | sub("Z.*";"")) as $date 
| select($date | older(7) | not)
| [.number, .user.login, .state, .created_at]
| @tsv
```

The above might need tweaking with respect to accessing the appropriate assignee information.

Comment: Can I get the command for linux ? I guess def is for python and I dont know python..

Comment: Invocation could be like: jq -r -f program.jq